# android fullscreen mode issue

Tags: android, fullscreen

I am able to create a fullscreen app with a simple linear layout, by settings the following properties.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Now if I add a EditText to the same linear layout (at the top), the app doesn't go to full screen mode anymore (The status bar is hidden though).

Am I doing anything wrong, or is it a bug in android ?

Answer (score 3):

It will be better to make your application work in full screen by adding the following attribute:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

in all the activities you declare in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: This works if I have only 1 activity in the application. When I have two activities, and I set fullscreen to one activity and the other activity is normal, I have the same problem again. The strange thing is if I replace the edittext with textview everything works as expected

Comment: Can't you just set all your activities to be full screen?

Comment: No, I want one activity to be fullscreen and the other one normal. But my main problem is why does an edittext behave differently from a TextView